# Why simple-mtpfs rsync stalls when transferring files?

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, android, rsync

I am mounting my USB-connected Android phone in my Linux box with the command

```
simple-mtpfs -o allow_root -o enable-move /mnt/phone
```

It mounts fine, I can see both my internal and external storages, move files, etc.

However, when trying to `rsync` a big folder (with no big files), it stalls, and take LOTS of time to transfer each tiny file. Completely unusable, of course.

Any, reason why this is happening, and how can I fix it?

In my old rooted phone I did this through SSH, but not sure how to do that with an unrooted phone.